# How to limit the SVN repository size?

Tags: svn

I'm going to set up SVN repositories for multiple projects. I wonder if it's possible to set per-project limits for repository size?

Comment: There is a good dupe of this over on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020490/limit-size-of-subversion-repository

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use SVN hooks to do this. For example, perhaps you could create a pre-commit hook that won't allow the commit if the project is already over a certain size.

Here's an example of a hook to limit the size of each individual commit (not quite what you want, but it may serve as a guide for my suggestion above):

http://www.davidgrant.ca/limit_size_of_subversion_commits_with_this_hook